# Keeping focus when moving DOM elements through angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use `*ngFor` to render a table of actions. The actions are sorted by priority, but priority may change when a user edits action details by interacting with `<input type="number">` in the table. I want sort order to update immediately on change.

The problem is that angular moves the table row by temporarily removing it from the DOM, which causes the `<input>` therein to lose focus as the user is typing. Is there a way I can prevent that?

**What I tried**

I have enabled DOM element reuse by specifying `trackBy`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of actions; trackBy: sameName">
  <td>{{a.roi}}</td>
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>
  <td><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.stateInfo" (ngModelChange)="updateActions()"></td>
</tr>
```

and was able to confirm in the developer tools that the DOM node is actually reused.

but setting DOM breakpoint on element removal still yielded the following stacktrace:

```
removeChild (platform-browser.js:1921)
removeChild (core.js:36584)
execRenderNodeAction (core.js:22849)
visitRenderNode (core.js:22815)
visitSiblingRenderNodes (core.js:22737)
visitRootRenderNodes (core.js:22720)
renderDetachView$1 (core.js:23404)
moveEmbeddedView (core.js:23375)
move (core.js:23716)
(anonymous) (common.js:4516)
forEachOperation (core.js:20644)
_applyChanges (common.js:4496)
ngDoCheck (common.js:4485)
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24492)
```

confirming that the ViewContainer moves the subview by temporarily removing it from the DOM, which I suspect causes the loss of focus.

Comment: Are the number of inputs static? If so, you can change the input visual order using css transform. The DOM will not be updated/change but visually, they will change as you are change the css.

Comment: Nice idea. Alas, the table is very dynamic. Rows may even appear or disappear when other rows are edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not finding a better approach, I opted to relax my requirements and delay updating the table until the user has hopefully finished typing:

in the template:

```
(ngModelChange)="updateRequest.emit()"
```

and in the component:

```
  updateRequest = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.updateRequest.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      takeUntil(this.death)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      const previouslyFocused = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
      this.update();
      setTimeout(() => { // after the DOM update
        previouslyFocused.focus(); 
      })
    })
  }
```

Better ideas are still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this to the input:

`[attr.id]="'action-input-' + a.roi"`

And update updateActions like this:

```
updateActions = (roi) => {

    // Sorting..

    // Find input
    const input = document.getElementById(`action-input-${roi}`);

    // Add to the end of the queue
    setTimeout(() => {
        input.focus()
    });
}
```

Do not forget to pass the parameter to updateActions:

`(ngModelChange)="updateActions(a.roi)"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to lose keystrokes if I keep tying while the table is updating.

Comment: One shouldn't use direct DOM access in Angular: use [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)